# What are the rules for verb bases(?)

Tags: verbs

I am quite confused as to how "見る" has suddenly changed into another word, albeit similar meaning when you do this: "見な."

My question is, how has the "na" appeared and the "ru" disappear?

Comment: Compare "confuse" with "confusion". They are different words but have a similar meaning. The final "e" changed into "ion". How did "ion" appear and "e" disappear?

Comment: Ah, I see the point you are trying to prove, @Earthling, however, I'm actually looking for a detailed explanation. Although analogy is a great way of explaining what happens, it does not explain how.

Comment: Then you have to explain what you mean when you ask "how"?

Comment: @Earthling, I'm wondering whether the way of adding "na" is out of the verb bases or is it out of some verb + noun or verb + verb.

Comment: You mean like 'what is this な here from'?

Comment: @Sjiveru Pretty much, it annoys me when a random concept waltz in, and there's nothing about it according to all the past researches I had.

Comment: You may want to get used to that happening, languages love doing that to you :P

Comment: @Sjiveru, I know, right? Hahahah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

見な is a shortened form of 見なさい, which, as you probably know, is form from the ます-stem + なさい.

These shortened forms (見な, 食べな, 帰りな, ...) are only used in spoken language.

Answer (score 8):

This な, expressing an order, can be thought of as coming from a shortened version of なさい:

> 見なさい！　→　見な！

It attaches to the 連用形 of a verb, which is the same form 〜ます attaches to:

> 見 + ます 　＝ 見ます
> 見 + な　　 ＝ 見な
>
> 動き + ます ＝ 動きます
> 動き + な　 ＝ 動きな

It is easily confused with another な, which expresses an order *not* to do something; this other な attaches to the 終止形, which is the plain form of a verb you find in a dictionary:

> 動く　　　　*to move*
> 動くな！　　Don't move!

Look at the difference between the two な forms:

> 見な！　　　Look!
> 見るな！　　Don't look!
>
> 動きな！　　Move!
> 動くな！　　Don't move!

If you don't understand why these verbs conjugate differently, you'll need to read in your textbook about the basic two types of verbs.  (These are called by various names, including "Type 1 and 2", "vowel and consonant stem" and 一段動詞・五段動詞.)

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer, however Earthling gave the answer earlier than you have. I am grateful though, considering that you took the time to answer to my question.

Comment: Although I should note that [終止形＋な has another possible meaning](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14229/1478).